# How to access file from another function

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm currently working on a C# WPF application which looks something like the following. What I am trying to do is this, the first button, when pressed, basically opens up a browse dialog box where you can select multiple files. I want access to those paths inside my other button too. Ultimately I want to be able to click on the browse button, select a file and then press the second button to perform a function on the paths. Any help will be appreciated!

```
private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //BROWSE BUTTON
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Multiselect = true;
    dlg.FileName = "Document"; 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";  
    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; 
    foreach (String file in dlg.FileNames)
    {
      // do something
    }
}    

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e, string p)
{
    myFunction(p);
}
```

Comment: what does this line represent `myFunction(p);` also what are you trying to do here `Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();`

Comment: @MethodMan basically want to call a function on the paths I get from the above

Comment: @MethodMan Also, didn't need the nullable line, I removed it.

Comment: Well, just read the documentation for C# on how an application is structured as multiple units.  This is not PHP:  it's a truly compiled language.  Units can use other units and thereby have access to the public things within them.

Comment: Why don't you just store the `dlg.FileNames` in the member variable?
This way, you'll be able to access it from another function

Comment: if you want a list of all the files do something like this even 
`var files = Directory.GetFiles(@filePath).Where(name => name.EndsWith(".txt")).ToList();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply have a private variable outside of the `Button_Click1` method which will hold the chosen file names.

```
string[] files;

private void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //BROWSE BUTTON
{
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Multiselect = true;
    dlg.FileName = "Document"; 
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";  
    dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; 

    Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

    if (result == true)
        files = dlg.FileNames;
    else
    {
        //Do something useful if the user cancels the dialog
    }
}
```

Then in your other method, simply reference the `files` variable, which will hold your array of chosen file names.

**Example usage:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    myFunction(files[i]);
}
```

The above code will iterate through each file in the array and call the `myFunction` method.

Comment: How will a separate function use it if that array has multiple elements?

Comment: Currently my program is written in a way that all my functions take a path in string form, not string[] form. So I think it'll be a lot of work changing the functions if I use string[].

Comment: @sparta93 I have edited my answer and provided an example of how you can call your function using a `for` loop.